# different status bar style for iphone/ipad in universal app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, statusbar

I recently updated my iPhone only app to an universal app and successfully submitted the update to the appstore. 
however, the UI-Designers behind the project would like to have individual status bar styles for each app. So the iPhone UI should have a solid black status bar where the iPad implementation should have it semi-transparent.

is there a way to tweak key/value-pairs in the info.plis file to achieve something like this?

thanks a lot for your ideas, 
sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
     // The device is an iPad running iOS 3.2 or later.
}
```

is recommended way of testing the device is iPad for iOS SDK >= 3.2

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIDevice` class to get device model type in your application

```
NSString* deviceType= [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
NSString* iPad = [NSString stringWithString:@"iPad"];
```

Now set the style of your status bar as per the model.

```
if([iPad compare:[deviceType substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,[iPad length])]] == NSOrderedSame )
{
   //This is iPad
}
else
{
   //This is iPhone/iPod
}
```

Comment: thx for answering, so you reckon that it is not possible to handle said issue from within an info.plist file then?

Comment: @samsam: For the optimum solution,We should get the info from system side and we are using `UIDevice` to obtain that,I'm not sure that `info.plist` would help you to sort the problem.